# CSS style being applied several times

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

From the chrome debugger:

```
element.style {
}

#title a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
    color: #FF33CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

(Everything below this is struck through)

```
nav a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#title a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
    color: #FF33CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#title a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
    color: #FF33CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why an element (title) is not showing up properly. This is what it looks like in the html body:

```
<div id="title">
    <a href="link.html">link</a>
</div>
```

I understand that when it's struck through, that style isn't being applied. What I don't understand is
a) Why is the nav style being called at all?
b) Why does the title style for links get called several times? The first time it seems to work, but the second time it's being struck through? (On the website, the element currently is only showing up in black text.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style is being called because the nav parent only applies to the first part of the selector. Basically you have this:

```
nav a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active{

//style

}
```

What you really want is:

```
nav a:link,
nav a:visited,
nav a:hover,
nav a:active{

//Style

}
```

The same thing goes for the `#title a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active`

---

My guess on why it is trying to use the same CSS multiple times would be that you have the same CSS in multiple places. E.G. you are either

- Importing the CSS twice
- Importing two CSS files with a duplicate style
- Duplicating the CSS in your one CSS file

Check the associated line numbers and see if they are the same (meaning it is actually using the exact same CSS twice) or different (meaning you have the same CSS in multiple places).

Comment: Oh, thanks! Clearly I didn't realize that about id tags.

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
#title a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
color: #FF33CC;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

but what it seems like you need is:

```
#title a:link, #title a:visited, #title a:hover, #title a:active {
color: #FF33CC;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

the id tag has to appear after each comma, otherwise you are styling ALL links, not just the ones with the #title id.

Hope that helps!